# SMTPAuthenticationError at /password-reset/ giving error after submiting email to pass reset form

Tags: html, css, django-views, django-templates

```
I have Django project of login and signup and I want to update the password in this Projects like we forget our passwd and with the help of this forget password we will send the reset password link to the mail id which will be registered by user, GETTING THIS ERROR AFTER SUBMITION OF EMAILID FOR VERIFICATION, when I enter email to get reset password link it is giving this error.
```

> Also, after seeing some suggestions in this website, I tried to access less secure apps setting in Gmail account but from May 2023 Gmail has stopped this service, so in my Gmail account it is not showing it.

SMTPAuthenticationError at /password-reset/
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8

```
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials iy5-20020a170903130500b001c9ba6c7287sm1178697plb.143 - gsmtp')
```

`EMAIL SEETING.PY`

```
        # email configs
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = str(os.getenv('EMAIL_USER'))
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = str(os.getenv('EMAIL_PASSWORD'))
```

> ```
> `
> ```

VIEWS.PY
`

```
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect 
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views import View
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')





class RegisterView(View):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'register.html'
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}')

            return redirect(to='login')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
    


class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    form_class = LoginForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        remember_me = form.cleaned_data.get('remember_me')

        if not remember_me:
            # set session expiry to 0 seconds. So it will automatically close the session after the browser is closed.
            self.request.session.set_expiry(0)

            # Set session as modified to force data updates/cookie to be saved.
            self.request.session.modified = True

        # else browser session will be as long as the session cookie time "SESSION_COOKIE_AGE" defined in settings.py
        return super(CustomLoginView, self).form_valid(form)
    

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # will redirect to the home page if a user tries to access the register page while logged
in
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(to='/')

        # else process dispatch as it otherwise normally would
        return super(RegisterView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class ResetPasswordView(SuccessMessageMixin, PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'password_reset.html'
    email_template_name = 'password_reset_email.html'
    subject_template_name = 'password_reset_subject.html'
    success_message = "We've emailed you instructions for setting your password, " \
                      "if an account exists with the email you entered. You should receive them shortly." \
                      " If you don't receive an email, " \
                      "please make sure you've entered the address you registered with, and check your spam folder."
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```